# Writing buffers to a Java channel: Thread-safe or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, buffer, channel

Consider the following code snippet, which simply writes the contents of `someByteBuffer` to the standard output:

```java
// returns an instance of "java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl"
WritableByteChannel w = Channels.newChannel(System.out);
w.write(someByteBuffer);
```

Java specifies that [channels are, in general, intended to be safe for multithreaded access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channel.html), while [buffers are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html).

So, I was wondering whether the above snippet requires synchronization, as it is invoking the `write` method of a channel (which is supposed to be thread-safe) on some buffer (which is not thread-safe).

I took a look at the [implementation of the `write` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/channels/Channels.java#446):

```java
public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
    int len = src.remaining();
    int totalWritten = 0;
    synchronized (writeLock) {
        while (totalWritten < len) {
            int bytesToWrite = Math.min((len - totalWritten),
                                        TRANSFER_SIZE);
            if (buf.length < bytesToWrite)
                buf = new byte[bytesToWrite];
            src.get(buf, 0, bytesToWrite);
            try {
                begin();
                out.write(buf, 0, bytesToWrite);
            } finally {
                end(bytesToWrite > 0);
            }
            totalWritten += bytesToWrite;
        }
        return totalWritten;
    }
}
```

Notice that everything is synchronized by the `writeLock`, except the first two lines in the method. Now, as the ByteBuffer `src` is not thread-safe, calling `src.remaining()` without proper synchronization is risky, as another thread might change it.

> Should I synchronize the line `w.write(someByteBuffer)` in the above snippet, or am I missing something and the Java implementation of the `write()` method has already taken care of that?

**Edit:** Here's a sample code which often throws a `BufferUnderflowException`, since I commented out the `synchronized` block at the very end. Removing those comments will make the code exception free.

```java
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
        b.put(new byte[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', '\n'});

        // returns an instance of "java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl"
        WritableByteChannel w = Channels.newChannel(System.out);

        int c = 10;
        Thread[] r = new Thread[c];
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            r[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable(b, w));
            r[i].start();
        }
    }    
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final ByteBuffer b;
    private final WritableByteChannel w;

    MyRunnable(ByteBuffer b, WritableByteChannel w) {
        this.b = b;
        this.w = w;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // synchronized (b) {
                b.flip();
                w.write(b);
            // }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference: Channels are thread-safe. For instance, consider a printer channel shared between multiple threads. If all threads start writing to the channel, their jobs will *not* be interleaved. On the other hand, if multiple thread can access the printer buffer, they can change it amidst printing, unless proper synchronization is performed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept; I am glad I could help. I also appreciate this nicely written, clear question. Nice idea to extra ">" quote the "summary question" in the end!

Comment: @GhostCat: All thanks to you! I think I pretty understand what's going on with channels, buffers, and thread safety :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is: if **your** setup allows *more than one thread* to tamper with that **buffer** object, then you are subject to threading issues. It is that simple!

The question is not if channel.write() is thread-safe. That is good to know, but not at the core of the problem!

The real question is: what is **your** code doing with that buffer?

What does it help that this channel implementation does lock **internally** on something when the *data* it is operating on ... is coming from the outside?!

You know, all kinds of things could happen on that `src` object coming into this method - *while* that channel is busy writing the buffer!

In other words: the question whether this code is "safe" fully depends on what *your* code is doing with that very `src` buffer object in parallel.

Given the OP's comment: the **core** point is: you have to ensure that any activity that makes use of that byte buffer is thread-safe. In the example given, we have two operations:

```
b.flip();
w.write(b);
```

Those are the only operation each thread will be doing; thus: when making sure that only **one** thread can make those two calls (as shown; by looking on the *shared* buffer object); then you are good.

It is really simple: if you have "shared data"; then you have to ensure that the threads reading/writing that "shared data" are *synchronized somehow* to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on what may go wrong. I edited the question and added a code with a "commented" `synchronized` block. Unless this block is uncommented, it often throws an exception. Am I now doing it right (assuming the comments are removed)?

Comment: See my updates to the answer; and yes; given your example code, removing those comments would "fix" the problem; and give you a thread-safe solution that should work correctly all the time.

Comment: `ByteBuffer` does not allow sub classes. But it isn’t needed to have a subclass to manipulate the `src` buffer while the write is in progress. By the way, if the goal is to let multiple threads write the same invariant contents, it’s better to just do one `flip()` before starting the threads, then, let each thread perform just a `w.write(b.asReadOnlyBuffer());`. This doesn’t copy the data, but creates an independent view having its own position, mark and limit, hence, there will be no interference between the threads at all, so no additional synchronization is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to lock the Channel if you are making multiple writes from multiple threads and want to ensure atomicity of those writes in which case you need to lock the System.out object.

If you shared a mutated data structure which is not thread safe across threads, you need to add locking. I would avoid using a ByteBuffer in multiple threads if you can.

Comment: The last sentence "avoid using a ByteBuffer in multiple threads if you can" is a golden advice! I'll try to keep it in mind in production environment. For educational purposes, however, I added a sample code to my question which demonstrates what can go wrong without synchronization. Notice that locking the ByteBuffer also works (rather than locking the Channel). Is doing the former a bad practice?

Comment: @M.S.Dousti locking the ByteBuffer works if it is effectively a global lock.  It would be very bad for performance though.